# Permission denied from pre-commit, unable to access local python build

Tags: python, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I am trying to commit some recent work and have been unable to get my precommit to work. I have changed permissions for this file, restarted the terminal, etc. Essentially the precommit script refuses to run. Any insight into this? Here is the error message I have been getting.

```
$ git commit -m "test commit"
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 14: C:\Users\Josiah\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: Permission denied
.git/hooks/pre-commit: line 14: C:\Users\Josiah\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe: Permission denied
```

also here is my current pre-commit file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# File generated by pre-commit: https://pre-commit.com


# start templated
INSTALL_PYTHON='C:\Users\Josiah\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe'
ARGS=(hook-impl --config=.pre-commit-config.yaml --hook-type=pre-commit)
# end templated

HERE="$(cd "$(dirname "$0")" && pwd)"
ARGS+=(--hook-dir "$HERE" -- "$@")

if [ -x "$INSTALL_PYTHON" ]; then
    exec "$INSTALL_PYTHON" -mpre_commit "${ARGS[@]}"
elif command -v pre-commit > /dev/null; then
    exec pre-commit "${ARGS[@]}"
else
    echo '`pre-commit` not found.  Did you forget to activate your virtualenv?' 1>&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: sounds like the store python got updated out from under you -- what happanes if you re-try `pre-commit install` ?

Comment: (personally I wouldn't recommend the windows store python -- I'd use the python.org installers)